# How to check the model of a phone from the Android SDK

Tags: android

I'm writing an andriod app that needs to check which model phone it is running on. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Build.Model](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#MODEL)

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#MODEL) to get the Build information.